Nested double quoting in bash
I have a complex command I am trying to run inside of docker. It sets the uid of existing user, chroots into some dir, and executes a "possibly complex command there".
docker (compose with stuff) run container /bin/bash -c "setuidgid.sh a:b && exec sudo -u user1 /bin/bash -c \" mkdir -p /chrootdir/proc && cp /proc/cpuinfo /chrootdir/proc/cpuinfo && sudo chroot /chrootdir echo hi1 && /bin/bash -c \\\"echo hi2 && /bin/bash -c \\\\\\\"echo hi3\\\\\\\"\\\"\" "

I get the expected ouput here - each level of nesting strips one backslash-character pair. However the resulting command is quite ugly and difficult to read. Is there any better way to achieve this? (I have made this command specifically nested a lot, there shouldn't reach a point in my code needing more than 'hi2'. This command just for sake of question)
NOTE: I don't want to use single quotes since this innermost command will call some arbitrary command which I may not know beforehand. Can guarantee no double quotes, but single quotes may be used.
PS. any improvements to the command itself can be left in comments. Have some reasons for the current solution, and even if a tailor made solution can be figured, my main goal is to figure out how I can nest quotes for an arbitrary command.
PS. I don't believe this is a duplicate, as most other questions on the topic work with nested quotes inside the substitution $().

typeset might make your life easier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72306694/oc-bash-how-to-execute-a-local-function-in-openshift-pod-with-oc-exec/72307217#72307217

Or reconsider nesting. If its impracticable, there is likely a better way.

there are three levels of script that need running - the docker run, the chroot and then opening shell there. Maybe I am missing a better solution, but this is all I saw.
Either way the main goal was to get a way to quote nicely in cases where it would be unavoidable (hence I mentioned to leave code suggestions in comments instead).

As you run some inline "scripts" with sudo then it's not possible to use exported functions, but ${var@Q} (or printf %q "$var") can help make the nested quoting less error prone:
Your original command:
docker ... run container /bin/bash -c "
    setuidgid.sh a:b &&
    exec sudo -u user1 /bin/bash -c \"
        mkdir -p /chrootdir/proc &&
        cp /proc/cpuinfo /chrootdir/proc/cpuinfo &&
        sudo chroot /chrootdir echo hi1 &&
        /bin/bash -c \\\"
            echo hi2 &&
            /bin/bash -c \\\\\\\"
                echo hi3
            \\\\\\\"
        \\\"
    \"
"

Recomposed command with ${var@Q}:
sh3="
    echo hi3
"
sh2="
    echo hi2 &&
    /bin/bash -c ${sh3@Q}
"
sh1="
    mkdir -p /chrootdir/proc &&
    cp /proc/cpuinfo /chrootdir/proc/cpuinfo &&
    sudo chroot /chrootdir echo hi1 &&
    /bin/bash -c ${sh2@Q}
"
sh0="
    setuidgid.sh a:b &&
    exec sudo -u user1 /bin/bash -c ${sh1@Q}
"

docker ... run container /bin/bash -c "$sh0"


You can try this structure :
docker run -i --rm ubuntu bash << 'EOF1'
    echo hi1
    bash << 'EOF2'
        echo hi2
        bash << 'EOF3'
            echo hi3
EOF3
EOF2
EOF1

